# Local Debian Server in VM and connect with iphone app

Tags: iphone, debian

How is a local Debian server setup so that an iphone app in the simulator can communicate with it?

I want to send files and data to the server from an iphone app. and for now I would like it to be locally using the simulator, rather than a device using a router.

Answer (score 0):

Enable NAT and you will find one network on the vm and two on the host computer, being one, a virtual network shared between the two of them. Then simply use their IP addresses as they appear in ifconfig.